# ajax request django , jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

```
#home.html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
alert("Example of a basic alert box in jquery");
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST' ,
    url: '{% url "filter.views.myajax" %}',
    datatype: 'json' ,
    async: true,
    data:{
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
        sentence: $('#word').val()
    },

    success: function(json) {
        $('#output').html(json.message);
    }
  });

  }



});

</script>
<title> My first </title>
<body>
<div id="output"> &nbsp; </div>
<div>
<form onsubmit="return false;">
{% csrf_token %}
Enter :- <br />
<input type="text" id="word" /> <br />
<button onclick="callajax()"> Submit </button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

#views.py
def myajax(request):
sentence= request.POST.get("sentence","")
response_data={}

try:
    response_data['title']='Hey its done ajax'
    response_data['message']=fil(sentence)

except:
    response_data['title']='NO'
    response_data['message']='NO'

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),content_type="application/json")
#url.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
url(r'^hello/$', 'filter.views.hello'),
url(r'^ajax/$', 'filter.views.myajax'),
)
```

I have been trying to implement ajax through jquery and update a div according to the response. There is no output shown when i click submit button. I have added the view.py and my template file here.
What is the issue here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace :

```
url: 'filter.views.myajax'
```

With

```
url: '{% url filter.views.myajax %}'

# **For Django >= 1.5 **

url: '{% url "filter.views.myajax" %}'
```

inside `$.ajax({})`

Comment: 'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in Django 1.5, see the docs. Its not working

Comment: Reverse for 'filter.views.myajax' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: [] .... i got this error now

Comment: post you url pattern from urls.py that is pointing to `filter.views.myajax` view .

Comment: Oh, I didn't make one , why do i need to make it ??

Comment: Its route . Its necessary in any MVC framework . in Django its defined in urls.py .

Comment: urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^hello/$', 'filter.views.hello'),
    url(r'^ajax/$', 'filter.views.myajax'),
)
i defined these two urls. Now in my ajax what should my url is it 'localhost/ajax'

Comment: you can edit in your question . and add this lines . here i can't figure out whether its commented or uncommented .

Comment: yes. if you are running in port 8000 then your url in firebug will be displayed like `localhost:8000/ajax`

Comment: url: 'localhost:8000/ajax' i addedd this in my ajax . still no output

Comment: No . don't add in ajax javascript. use firbug to debug . u can see error in console if any .

Comment: No this url i added in Jquery function where i have to put my url.

Comment: `{% url "filter.views.myajax" %}` is appropriate . you checked in firebug ? which javascript error its displaying ?

Comment: I tested the onclick function is unable to call the function callajax() , why any idea?

Comment: I did that thing as well. Still no output . i have updated the question